# Dynamically content bootstrap modal dialog from PHP Symfony2

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, bootbox

I'm working with [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/)  to render a forms with symfony 2. So I've a one trouble when I wanna change the content dynamically I don't know how.

So this is that I wanna

1. I click a button that render a Form from controller embebed inside of modal dialog

```php
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-new" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#agregarRonda">
          Add My Entity
        </button>

        <div  style="display: none;"  class="modal fade" id="agregarRonda" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"  aria-hidden="true">
           <div class="modal-dialog">
             <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add my Entity</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                        {% embed "projete:MyEntity:newMyEntity.html.twig"  %}
                        {% endembed %}

                  </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

2.When I render a Form newMyentity.html.twig this has a button that redirecting to this method inside of my controller on symfony like:

```php
public function createMyEntityAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $entity = new MyEntity();
    $form = $this->createMyEntityForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) 
    {
         if( ifNotExist( $entity->getDescription() )   )
         {
            //Do the right things
         }
         else{
           /*
            * Return content to the modal dialog and don't hide modal dialog? 
            */ 
         }
    }
}
```

So, I call a method ifNotExist to check somethings.If return false I wish to send content to the modal dialog without hide the modal dialog and modify the content.

**How can I do it?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public function createMyEntityAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $entity = new MyEntity();
    $form = $this->createMyEntityForm($entity);
    if ($request->getMethod()=="POST"){
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) 
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return new Response($entity->getId(),201); 
        }
    }

    return $this->render('yourFormTemplate.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView() );
}
```

Your entity:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
...
/**
 * MyEntity
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table()
 */
class MyEntity
{
    ...
    /**
     * 
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message ="Plz enter the description")
     */
    private $description;
    ...
}
```

Your JS:

```
$('#yourAddBtnId').on('click', function(){
    var $modal = $('#yourModalId')
    $.get("yourURL", null, function(data) {
      $modal.find('modal-body').html(data);
    })
    // create the modal and bind the button
    $('#yourModalId').dialog({
      buttons: {
        success: {
          label: "Save",
          className: "btn-success",
          callback: function() {
            that = this;
            var data = {};
            // get the data from your form
            $(that).find('input, textarea').each(function(){
              data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
            })
            // Post the data
            $.post( "yourURL", function(data , status) {
                if ( "201" === status){
                  $modal.modal('hide');
                }
                else {
                  $modal.find('modal-body').html(data);
                }      
            });
          }
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: I did not the same that you put here, but is was an inspiration to get the thing that I wanted,  I forget tell you :D